# The point of use of return statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return

I'm curious of what's the point of using return statement.

```
def give_me_five():
    five = 5
    return five

number = give_me_five()
print("Here's what I got from give_me_five():", number)
```

Above code shows the following result.

```
Here's what I got from give_me_five(): 5
```

As you can see, when you can just type 5 in print("Here's what I got from give_me_five():", 5) like this, what's exactly the point of using return statement and why does it need to even make a function to set a value 5?

Comment: Well.. It returns the value?

Comment: The function is not needed. In fact, none of this code is "needed" (what's the use of printing that text?). I assume it's just an example.

Comment: Assuming that this is not philosophical navel-gazing, you use `return` to designate the value of a function call. If your function should reasonably return a value (e.g. `"something\n".strip()` should give back `"something"`), you'll have to `return` from it, or it will have a value of `None`.

Comment: As a more cogent example: try writing code that asks for the user's name, then printing "Hello, <name>!" Then try writing a function that capitalizes the name before giving it back to be printed.

Comment: these are 2 questions, totally unrelated. the first is "why use return?" the second is "why do i need a function to give me five?" if you don't know why you should or shouldn't be using return, you should go do a basic programming tutorial before coming to stackoverflow with questions.

Comment: I disagree with the fact that this question be downvoted. It is extremely basic, but it is not a bad question.

Answer (score 2):

#### Why you need return

Try removing `return`. It then prints

```
Here's what I got from give_me_five(): None
```

If you do not return `5`, you have no way to recover it outside your function.

That is why you need `return`. But then...

#### Why you need functions

In your example, your function always returns the same value, so it is not needed, but suppose you have a more complex function that returns based on an input.

```
def give_me_more(n)
    return n + 1
```

This function does not always return the same value, so it is a bit more useful. But then you should ask: wait, can't I just replace that function by `n + 1` in my code?

#### Can't we do without function?

Well yes, but keep in mind that functions can be way more complex than the above examples.

```
def get_factors(n):
    factors = []
    for i in range(int(math.sqrt(n))):
        if n % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
            factors.append(n / i)
    return sorted(factors)
```

Do you want to insert this code in your script everytime you want to get the factors of a number? Of course not, and to be able to reuse code you need to write functions. Which in turn requires `return`.